# How do I get query string params in NextJS middleware

Tags: javascript, next.js, middleware

I'm using NextJS middleware and can get the `nextUrl` object from the request, which includes things like pathname, but how do I get query string parameters from within the middleware? I can see it comes back as part of the string returned by href which I could then parse myself but I was wondering if it is returned in an object of it's own?

e.g.

```
export const middleware = (request) => {
  const { nextUrl: { query } } = request;
  ...
};
```

where `query` equals

```
{
  param1: 'foo',
  param2: 'bar',
  etc.
}
```

Answer (score 26):

`nextUrl` object already includes `searchParams` which is a valid `URLSearchParams` instance.

E.G. usage

```
export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    if(req.nextUrl.searchParams.get('flag')) {
        return NextResponse.rewrite('/feature');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

As @j-cue said above but I also discovered you can get `search` from `nextUrl`.

e.g.

```
export const middleware = (request) => {
  const { nextUrl: { search } } = request;
  const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(search);
  const params = Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries());
};
```

Answer (score 2):

As of Next.js 13.4 you can get search params like this from the url:

```
export const GET = async (request, { params }) => {
   try{
        
        // Path Params are received from {params} variable
        //You can receive search params as below:
        // UrlPath = `/api/prompt/${post._id.toString()}?type=DELETE`
        //The search params [type, method] for above url

        const {type, method} = Object.fromEntries(request.nextUrl.searchParams);
        console.log(type, method);
        if(type === "DELETE" && method === "GET"){
            //Perform an action
        }

        return new Response("Action performed", {status: 200});
   }
   catch(err){
    console.log(err);
   }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You might want to just extract it from a location:

```
const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const params = Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries());
```

Comment: The question was specifically about [NextJS middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware), so this answer using `window.location.search` doesn't work.

Comment: irrelevant to question  -1